# Nodejs : callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, callback

In the below code , I am authenticating username and password user enters with the details from my mongo database . If successful , redirect to /main route (index.ejs) . I am getting error :- **callback is not a function** . 
I am new to nodejs . I can't figure out where and why I am getting this error .

***app.js***

```
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  var path = require('path');
  var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
  var logger = require('morgan');
  var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  var urlencoder = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true});
  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  var url = 'mongodb://<username>: <password>@ds141434.mlab.com:41434/teacherspro'; // using mLab 
  app.set('view engine' , 'ejs');           // ejs as view engine

var index = require('./routes/index');    // providing routes
var users = require('./routes/users');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); 


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/main', index);       
app.use('/users', users);


 app.get('/login' , function(req,res,next){  // rendering homepage
    console.log('\r');    
    res.render('login');   // rendering login.ejs
    console.log('rendered master page!');
    next();
 });

MongoClient.connect(url , function(err,db){
    if (err) return;

    app.post('/login' , urlencoder , function(req,res,next){
        app.use(bodyParser.json());

    var UserName = req.body.UserName;
    var Password = req.body.Password;

     db.collection('project1').find({ '$and' : [ {"UserName" : UserName} , {"Password" : Password} ]} , {_id : 0}).forEach(function(pes){  // authenticating username and password

         if(true)
          {
              console.log(pes);
              res.redirect('/main');
          }
      });
   });
    db.close(); 
    next();
});

app.listen(5050);      
module.exports = app;
```

***Index.js***

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
     MongoClient.connect(url , function(err,db){
        if (err) return;
        db.collection('project1').find({"UserName" : "karan"} , {_id : 0}).forEach(function(pes){
            console.log(pes);
            res.render('index', {Name : pes});
        });
   });
});

module.exports = router;
```

***login.ejs***

```
<form id = 'login' method = POST action = '/login'> 
        <label for = 'Username'> UserName </label>
        <input type = 'text' name = 'UserName' value = ''>
        <br />
        <label for = 'Password'> Password </label>
        <input type = 'password' name = 'Password' value = ''>
        <br />
        <center> <input type ="submit" value = "submit" /> </center>
        <br />
</form>
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the error? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: There are no `logger` or `cookieParser` variables in your first script

Comment: Added . It still doesn't work

Comment: What does `bodyparser.json()` return? Is that a function?

Comment: Its a middleware

Comment: @KNIGHTMAHAJAN it'd be much easier if you put the stack trace, before we start asking for every single variable that might or not be a function.

Answer (score -1):

Post callback has the following form:
app.post(path, callback);

Check the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html). app.post

Just remove `urlencoder` param.

Comment: then its not able to post info . It then says  Error :"UserName is not defined"

Comment: You don't have next() in the index middleware so your next middleware will not be executed. Thus, app.post will not be executed at all.

Comment: I don't see the code for users middleware so maybe you should add next() there as well